Nextjs and prisma: TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts"
I am starting on the Nextjs world and i wanted to try the prisma ORM but i'm facing some errors.
So basicaly other thing what i am in doubt here is the fact that prior this erros i was getting another error saying that i can't use modules inside the project, and i can't understand that too.
When i try to insert data inside the database using prisma i get this error:
TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\Users\Username\Documents\Repositorios\resumos\src\app\api\hello\route.ts
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:143:22)
    at async ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:7)
    at async ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:45)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:21) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'

This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "teste",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.17.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.411.0",
    "next": "14.2.5",
    "next-themes": "^0.3.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.4.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify/react": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prisma": "^5.17.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Sorry for any errors in the writing i am not a fluent english speaker.
